# How to run junit test without pre set data

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito

**Basically I want to run the test on a clean slate, so I don't want @PostConstruct populating the data field.**

I have a private static variable in service class that gets data loaded from the repository upon build success. Is there a way to run unit tests without this data? (with fresh classes)

In the test I'm mocking a repository's `getData` function but there is an `if empty` statement in there. Since on build, the static variable is populated the tests won't use the mocked function, so the test fails.

What I found works is to call an `empty variable` function of the service within a `@Before` annotation. But this is not a stable solution.

sample of code:

```
private static List<Data> data = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<Data>());

@PostConstruct
private List<Data> populateData() {

  data = repo.findData();

  return data;
}

public List<Data> getData() {

  if (data.size() == 0) {
    populateData();
  }
  return data;
}
```

test:

```
@Mock
private Repository repo;

@Mock
private static Data data;

@InjectMocks
private Service service;

private List<Data> rows = new ArrayList<Data>();

@Before
public void mockMethodSetup() {

  //service.evictData();

  data.setValue(1);

  when(repo.findData()).thenReturn(data);

}

@Test
public void shouldReturnDataResponse() {
  List<Data> dataReturned= service.getData();
  assertEquals("Response was not equal to the mock.", dataReturned, data);
}
```

Comment: `Repository.findData()` - is `Repository` a singleton?

Comment: Repository is not a singleton, it is an interface that extends JpaRepository

Comment: I changed it to trial and error it

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand you try to replace the static `data` field with something different in your test.

You can do that using `Reflections`: [`link`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3301635/change-private-static-final-field-using-java-reflection).

---

This may or may not work, depending on whether your `repo.findData()` call works or produces an exception. I suggest that you do not bring in any know-how to the UnitTest regarding the `@PostConstruct` annotation, so that the method will not be executed.

---

Also if you define @Mock for `data` you'll need to define behaviour for it.
Note that `data` should not be a static field in your test.

Ps.:
`@InjectMocks` doesn't have any effect on static fields.

Comment: Basically I want to run the test on a clean slate, so I don't want ````@PostConstruct```` populating the data field. Does the change Reflections make stay with the service class?

Comment: What `Runner` do you use that invokes `@PostConstruct`? If you use reflecftions after the initialisiation has taken place it will override it, however if another instance of the object is created it might override it again.

Comment: I'm using MockitoJunitRunner which works locally but fails on CI GitLab because it has to build (and so @PostConstruct) and therefore the data is populated before the tests. Therefore the ````if```` in  Service.getData() wont allow me to populate it.

Comment: `MockitoJunitRunner` has no concept of `@PostConstruct`. If the method is invoked it must come from somewhere else. Check your `CI GitLab` configuration.

Comment: GitLab CI pipeline builds before it runs unit tests

Comment: This turned into a configuration issue. Trying asking another question for this, I can't answer that.